# Laravel Eloquent - Accessor not working with relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two model `Post` and `PostImage`. In my `PostImage` model I have set `accessor` that will concat the image URL to image. I am getting my image response but URL is not prefixed.

Here my `PostImage` model

```
class PostImage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'post_image_id';


    /**
     * Get the image
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
     */
    protected function name(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => config('custom.filepath.products.resize128') . $value,
        );
    }
}
```

I am calling `return Post::with('images')->get()` and here is the response -

```
{
        "post_id": 4,
        "customer_id": 1,
        "title": "a",
        "description": "Its a description",
        "target_price": 3000,
        "date_of_availability": "2023-02-04",
        "condition": "abc",
        "latitude": "-31.95303000",
        "longitude": "115.85360000",
        "attributes": "{\"list\":[{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":\"Red1\"},{\"title\":\"Frame\",\"value\":\"Metal Frame1\"}]}",
        "created_at": "2023-02-06T08:01:42.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-06T08:01:42.000000Z",
        "images": [
            {
                "post_image_id": 1,
                "post_id": 4,
                "name": "167567052363e0b3fbc2fe9.jpg",
                "created_at": "2023-02-06T08:02:06.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-06T08:02:06.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "post_image_id": 2,
                "post_id": 4,
                "name": "167567052663e0b3fe46bf8.jpg",
                "created_at": "2023-02-06T08:02:06.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-06T08:02:06.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: is `config('custom.filepath.products.resize128')` returning a value besides `null`?

Comment: Its returning a string `products/h128w128/`

Comment: do you have an alias for `Attribute` set at the top of that file?

Comment: @lagbox I was missing use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute; thanks to pointing out. Its resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;`